# How to import and combine multiple files in R?

Tags: r, join, import, multiple-file-upload

I have two questions:

- How can I import multiple files?
- How can I combine different files based on part of their file name? I can import files in either .xlsx or .DAT.

For example, for the person x I have these files:

1234_12w_1_m

1234_12w_2_m

1234_32w_1_m

1234_32w_2_m

The first part of the file name is the person ID (1234). The second part of the name is the period (12w or 32w).

I want to join files based on the ID and the week:

week 12:

1234_12w_1_m
+
1234_12w_2_m -> Once this has been done, calculate the mean of a variable of the dataset.

week 32:

1234_32w_1_m
+
1234_32w_2_m -> Once this has been done, calculate the mean of a variable of the dataset.

I hope I've explained that clearly.

Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

To import a file, you can use the read.delim() function. You can stack the dataframes (or *union* them) using rbind().

```
df1 <- read.delim('path\file1.dat', sep = '\t')
df2 <- read.delim('path\file2.dat', sep = '\t')


stacked <- rbind(df1, df2)
```

After that, you are able to aggregate as you would on any other dataset. For example:

```
mean <- mean(stacked$variable)
```